# Preventing jQuery change event from triggering via .val()

Tags: jquery

I have a select dropdown that is initialized programatically using jquery .val(). There is a change event associated to this element, that needs to work differently depending on whether user is changing value or it is changed programatically via $select.val(). What is the best way to achieve this?

```
$select.change(function() {
    // always execute:
    ...
    // don't execute on .val(): [how to check this?]
    ...
});
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Can you provide some code? Have you tried anything?

Comment: As a suggestion, your title doesn't seem to match your scenario (it makes it sound like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Perhaps something like *Preventing jQuery change event from triggering via .val()*, or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use standard **addEventListener** function on the DOM element that **will not** be triggered when you use jquery **val** function to set value.

```
document.getElementById('myOption').addEventListener('change', function(){
    alert('value changed by user to: ' + this.value);
});
```

Now even if you use jquery to change the value `$('#myOption').val(3)` it will not trigger the event.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9gbqr/)**